# Can't access PayPal account without phone

Tags: paypal

I tried logging into my PayPal account and the only way to log in is by entering a phone number I no longer have. I do not live in the United States and my phone is unable to make international calls. How can I access my PayPal account without a phone? Is there a chat support?

Comment: Do you have access to the email you used to sign up? There are definitely links on the login page to either "Change" (your sign-in from phone to email) or that you're having trouble logging in.

Comment: @jonsca That doesn't work as after receiving the verification code to my email, it then asks me again to receive an SMS or phone call from them, to the phone number I already lost.

Comment: Have you got the solution? I'm in the same situation...

Comment: @Blaszard re: Your edit, In addition to the `phone-number` tag being a bit extraneous, I was afraid that your title edit changed the slant on the question to be about using a new number to access the old account, rather than accessing the account without *any* phone.

Comment: re: Not working.  Yeah, that's a bummer... mine was just a suggestion, which is why I didn't post it as an answer.  Not sure what to tell you.